# How can I find the css error when I run a jquery plugin on IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I used a jquery plugin named 'layer' in my project.
It can be run correctly on chrome and firefox.
But there is a css error when I used IE8,the window display in unexpected way.
There are a lot of window ,but only one runs incorrectly.
I want to know how can I find the bug.

Comment: ummm a developer tool?

Comment: Yes,I just wondered how this happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think there is noany way to find exactly where or in which line your error is... just try to know about IE8 tag using or check this link may be it helps you..

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them/

Comment: It's really useful to me. Thanks.